# Select listview column with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listview

I have 2 columns, "a" and "b". "b" is hidden while "a" don't.
I want that when a mouse is clicked over "a" column, text in "b" column (remeber is hidden) shows in a dialog.

At the moment I have this selector that shows "a" text column sucssesfull:

```
<div id="dialog"
style="display:none;padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;min-height:310px;">
<div id="content" style="width:100%;overflow:auto;height:120px;"></div>
```

I prepare the dialog:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 460,
    title: "Message",
    buttons: {
        "Cerrar": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

// event when mouse over "a" is clicked

```
$('.a').click(
        function () {
            var text = $(this).attr('data-desc');
            $('#content').html(text);
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }
    );
```

**Listview:**
// this is the column where I clic

```
style="overflow:hidden;"
        **CssClass="a"**
        data-desc='<%# Eval("subject") %>'  
        runat="server" 
        text='<%# Eval("subject") %>'
        Visible="true" />
```

// I want to show this column -text-
// on a dialog

```
<span
 id="coment" 
 style="width:0%;vertical-align:top">
 <cc1:SWCLabel 
     **cssclass="b"** 
     style="overflow:hidden;"
     data-desc='<%# Eval("Text") %>'  
     runat="server" 
     text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'
     Visible="false" />
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having with the code you've posted?

Comment: Yes, it is showing a diferent listvew column text.

Comment: Anyway, I've solved it by putting a custom attribute in the "a" column and select it in the jquery "a" column click.